# Verse package typesets in the left margin

Tags: margins, verse

When using the `verse` environment with the `verse` package, the `\flagverse` are typeset in the margin:

```
\begin{verse}
\begin{altverse}
\flagverse{1.} Quel est l'enfant qui est né ce soir\\
Inconnu des grands de la terre ?\\
Quel est l'enfant qui est né ce soir\\
Que les pauvres ont voulu recevoir.
\end{altverse}

\begin{altverse}
\flagverse{\textsc{Refrain≡}} Il suffit d'un enfant ce soir\\
Pour unir le ciel et la terre.\\
Il suffit d'un enfant ce soir\\
Pour changer notre vie en espoir.
\end{altverse}

\begin{altverse}
\flagverse{2.} Quel est l'enfant qui est né ce soir\\
Pour changer la nuit en lumière.\\
Quel est l'enfant qui est né ce soir\\
Tout joyeux comme un feu dans le noir.
\end{altverse}

\begin{altverse}
\flagverse{3.} Quel est l'enfant qui est né ce soir\\
Au delà de toutes frontières.\\
Quel est l'enfant qui est né ce soir\\
Sinon Dieu que je peux recevoir
\end{altverse}
\end{verse}
```

[image: flagverse in margin]

How can this be avoided?

Comment: The `\flagverse` bits are typeset so that their right end will be at `\vleftskip` distance from the left margin of the verses. Set `\vleftskip` to .5em or so. The verse indentation uses `\leftmargini`.

Comment: Actually, `\vleftskip` will move the text, but not the label to the left of the text. I've got to find something else.

Comment: If you were able to solve the issue, why don't you add an answer here?

Comment: Well, I haven't really. I've kept it as it is, but I'm not very happy with it, still.

Comment: @ℝaphink This is the documented behaviour for `\flagverse`: I'm not sure there is much we can say about it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about 'by design' behaviour.